# Has Anyone concatenated two videos using ffmpeg

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg

I am a newbie to android development and my app is like vine app , but i am not able to concatenate two videos using ffmpeg libs . Can anyone provide a sample code or some reference

Comment: read the [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Not sure why this is attracting the down votes - using ffmpeg on Android is not trivial and most of the documentation (including the link above) is geared towards the command line use of ffmpeg. Understanding how to use the C libraries directly is tricky in my experience, but if you do want to go this way there are samples here:https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Mp4Parser , was pretty easier than ffmpeg , nd sdk was much smaller in size

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ffmpeg libraries compiled for and available on Android to allow this to work - they are not part of the standard Android environment.

One approach is to use the command line FFMPEG 'program' wrapped so that it can be accessed programatically via a Java API from Android. This has the advantage that it uses the same syntax as the command line version and there will be lots of support/information on parameters usage etc on the web. The key disadvantage is that the ffmpeg program was not really designed to be run this way so it may not be as efficient as using the libraries directly, and error handling may be tuned for command line output.

There are a number of projects you can use/reference that will allow you include ffmpeg in an Adnroid project this way and then call ffmpeg using the same syntax the command line version does. One example is:

- http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

If you do want to use the ffmpeg C libraries directly there are exmaples, as mentioned in the comment above, here (although there is no specific concat example):

- https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply , really appreciated !!!!

ill implement it and will tell the result